How can I obtain the possible maximum of auto value among flex items?
If there is a flex item with such flexbox values set to it flex: 1 0 220px; can I get by the means of javascript its dimensions (width, height) that would be applied to it when the values become flex: 1 0 auto;?
Is the only way to get these dimensions to set flex: 1 0 auto; to the item at first and only then call the needed javascript api method?
My issue is to (smoothly) switch flex items' width values from the fixed 220px to the maximum auto among them. However, I don't know how to obtain this maximum before auto is actually set.

Animations to/from auto are tricky and you will need to find a way around it, that works for you. Basically you want to render it hidden somewhere/-how, measure it and apply transitions accordingly, see e.g. here

You can retrieve the maximum possible width. It also depends on what flex values you've set for other flex-items.
Using JavaScript, for a brief instant, you can set flex: 1 0 auto; on that flex-item, use getBoundingClientRect() on it to record its max width. Then, revert to flex: 1 0 220px; in the next line.


const green = document.querySelector('.green');

// Initial width with flex: 1 0 10px;
const initialWidth = green.getBoundingClientRect().width;

// Remove any transition (animation) from flex-item here
green.style.transition = "none";
  
// Momentarily (for few milliseconds) changing flex to flex: 1 0 auto; to get max width
green.style.flex = "1 0 auto";
const maxWidth = green.getBoundingClientRect().width; // Max width retrieved
  
// Immediately reverting back to (initial) flex: 1 0 10px;
green.style.flex = "1 0 10px";

// Add the transition (animation) back to the flex-item here
green.style.transition = "all 0.3s";

// Current width after reverting:
const currWidth = green.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  
console.log('Initial width with flex: 1 0 10px; - ', initialWidth);
console.log('Maximum width with flex: 1 0 auto; - ', maxWidth);
console.log('Current width after reverting - ', currWidth);
body {
  width: 90vw;
  color: black;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.container div {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1 0 10px;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
}
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="red">Red</div>
    <div class="green">Green with more content to occupy more space when flex basis is auto</div>
    <div class="blue">Blue</div>
  </div>
</body>




I've corrected my answer. I had previously misunderstood your question. You can get the max possible width like this. If you come across a better solution, please let me know. I'm interested in this problem/question.
